# python script works on windows but not in linux

Tags: python, linux, windows

I am working on a project where I want to import a huge number of data in arangodb. All the data are in .xlsx form with multiple worksheets. So I wrote a script that converts the .xlsx files to json files (one json file for each worksheet) and then establishes a connection with arango db and does bulk import of data in arangodb. So I wrote the script in jupyter notebook installed in a windows pc with the latest Anaconda version and it works like a charm with either local or remote database connections. So after I saw that the code works I copied the script to my CentOS7 virtual server and ran it and it crashed. I ran it in a physical machine with ubuntu 19.10 and it crashed also. Both linux machines were updated, and worked also with the latest Anaconda version. Also the script was ran both in command line as .py file and as .ipynb file from jupyter notebook in all the machines (windows and linux). In windows it works perfectly in linux it crashes when it starts to convert the first .xlsx file. The code for the script is this:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from xlsx2csv import Xlsx2csv as x2csv
import os
import hashlib
import json
import numpy as np
from arango import ArangoClient
import glob

filelist = []
hash_dict = {}
current_folder = os.getcwd()
for file in os.listdir(current_folder):
    if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
        filelist.append(file)

#create a list of all worksheets contained in the worksheet
def create_sheet_list(file):
    with ZipFile(file) as zipped_file:
        summary = zipped_file.open(r'xl/workbook.xml').read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(summary, "xml")
    sheets = [sheet.get("name") for sheet in soup.find_all("sheet")]
    return sheets

#create an array of dataframes from all the worksheets
def create_dataframes(file):
    xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
    xl.sheet_names
    dfs = {sheet: xl.parse(sheet) for sheet in xl.sheet_names}
    return dfs

def create_json(file,sheets,dfs):
    print(("The file contains {} sheets").format(len(sheets)))
    count = 0
    for i in sheets:
        json_filelist = []
        count = count + 1
#produce the dataframe and check if there are any encoding errors
        try:
            df = dfs[i]
            new_header = df.iloc[0]
            df = df[1:]
            df.columns = new_header
            df = df.fillna(0)
            hash_str_name = file.strip('.xlsx')+("_{}.json").format(i.replace(' ','_'))
            hash_str=int(hashlib.sha1(hash_str_name.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest(), 16) % (10 ** 10)
            values = str(hash_str)
            df['Hash']=np.nan
            df['Hash']= df['Hash'].fillna(value=values)
            #hash_dict.update({hash_str_name : values})
            hash_dict[hash_str_name] = values
            json_file = df.reset_index().to_json(new_path+"/"+file.strip('.xlsx')+("_{}.json").format(i.replace(' ','_')), orient = "records")
#For the dataframes that will get an error because of encoding a different way of conversion will be used
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            x2csv(file, outputencoding="utf-8").convert(file.strip('.xlsx')+('{}.csv').format(i.replace(' ','_')),count)
            df = pd.read_csv(file.strip('.xlsx')+('{}.csv').format(i.replace(' ','_')), header = 1)
            hash_str_name = file.strip('.xlsx')+("_{}.json").format(i.replace(' ','_'))
            hash_str=int(hashlib.sha1(hash_str_name.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest(), 16) % (10 ** 10)
            values = str(hash_str)
            df['Hash']=np.nan
            df['Hash']= df['Hash'].fillna(value=values)
            #hash_dict.update({hash_str_name : values})
            hash_dict[hash_str_name] = values
            json_file = df.reset_index().to_json(new_path+"/"+file.strip('.xlsx')+("_{}.json").format(i.replace(' ','_')), orient = "records")
            os.remove(file.strip('.xlsx')+('{}.csv').format(i.replace(' ','_')))

#Create connection with the Database
def create_db_connection():
    client = ArangoClient(hosts='http://127.0.0.1:8529')
    db = client.db('CEM', username='root', password='123456')
    return db

#Get the list of the .json files from all the folders
def list_of_json():
    path =  os.getcwd()
    folders = os.listdir(path)
    json_names = []
    for folder in folders:
        files = glob.glob(path+"/"+folder+"/"+"*.json")
        if len(files)>0:
            json_names.append(files)
    return json_names

#Get the list of the collections in the database
def list_of_collections(sheets,db):
    for col in sheets:
        col = col.replace(' ','_')
        if db.has_collection(col):
            collect = db.collection(col)
        else:
            collect = db.create_collection(col)
    collection = db.collections()
    collection = [i['name'] for i in collection if i['name'][0].isupper()]
    return collection

#Import the data from the .json files to the appropriate collections
def import_data(json_names,collection, db):
    for x in json_names:
        for y in x:
            for z in collection:
                with open(y, "r") as json_file:
                    if y.endswith("{}.json".format(z)):
                        data = json.load(json_file)
                        z = db.collection(z)
                        z.import_bulk(data)

for file in filelist:
    try:
#create the folder where the .json files from that UFED will be stored
        new_folder = os.mkdir(os.getcwd()+"/"+file.strip('.xlsx'))
#get the path for the new folder
        new_path = "{0}/{1}".format(os.getcwd(), file.strip('.xlsx'))
    except FileExistsError:
#if the folder already exists just get its path
        new_path = "{0}/{1}".format(os.getcwd(), file.strip('.xlsx'))
    print(new_path)
#print the name of the file that's being analyzed so that we have a measure of progress
    print(("Now I am working with {} file").format(file))
#call the functions and run the program
    create_sheet_list(file)
    create_dataframes(file)
    sheets = create_sheet_list(file)
    dfs = create_dataframes(file)
    create_json(file,sheets,dfs)
df_dict = pd.DataFrame(list(hash_dict.items()), index = None, columns = ["File_name", "Hash_num"])
df_dict.to_json(current_folder+"/hash_list.json", orient = "records")
create_db_connection()
db = create_db_connection()
#create_collections(sheets,db)
list_of_json()
json_names = list_of_json()
list_of_collections(sheets,db)
collection = list_of_collections(sheets,db)
import_data(json_names,collection,db)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hello! I advise you to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Can you elaborate on what you mean by "it crashed"? Was an exception raised? Did something segfault? Did your computer catch on fire?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write it. So when I ran the script in jupyter notebook I got an error " Kernel restarting
The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically" and when I ran it from command line I got an error :
"Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: "in linux it crashes when it starts to convert the first .xlsx file" Does it consistently crash? Do you know which line it crashes on? Because you haven't supplied any xlsx files we can't test anything for you.

Comment: GordonAitchJay. To answer your questions. I can't provide any xlsx file because they are internal documents and I can't get them outside of my company. It crashes when it starts to execute the create_json(file,sheets,dfs) function after it starts writing the json files and finds one of the biggest worksheets. So if you see the code I get the result from 
```print(("The file contains {} sheets").format(len(sheets)))```
the smaller json files are created and it crashes when it finds a big worksheet with some thousands lines in it. And yes it crashes consistently with all files